# How to use Button bar as navigation tabs ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

Using the awesome ionic framework, I'm using the Button bar like the pic below :

[image]

But I want when I press a button, it should remain pressed and the others off, and when I press the second, it remains pressed and the others off.

like this :

[image]

here is the code :

```
<div class="button-bar">
  <a class="button">First</a>
  <a class="button">Second</a>
  <a class="button">Third</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Add an active class to the button, guy. On click, remove the active class on all the siblings and add it to the new active link. Don't overthink things.

Comment: @Yasser B.: did my answer prove to be useful? If yo, consider it marking as an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 8):

I would use `ng-class` to change the button.

Simply make a class of an active button, and then add the logic into it.

```
<div class="button-bar">
    <a class="button" ng-click="clicked(1)" ng-class="{'active': var == 1}">First</a>
    <a class="button" ng-click="clicked(2)" ng-class="{'active': var == 2}">Second</a>
    <a class="button" ng-click="clicked(3)" ng-class="{'active': var == 3}">Third</a>
</div>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.clicked = function(num) {
    $scope.var = num;
}
```

This would make a button 'active' in Angular.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working demo from [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/waoyYw), copy pasted below. You can run this code example directly here on StackOverflow by clicking the `Run code snippet` button below.

*Note: it's not a generic solution, but should get you moving in the right direction.*

```js
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.button = {};
  $scope.button.first = {};
  $scope.button.second = {};
  $scope.button.third = {};
    
  $scope.click = function(button){
    $scope.button.first.clicked = false;
    $scope.button.second.clicked = false;
    $scope.button.third.clicked = false;
    
    button.clicked = true;
  };

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">    
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body class="padding" ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <div class="button-bar">
      <a class="button" ng-model="button.first" ng-click="click(button.first)" ng-class="button.first.clicked?'button-positive':'button-energized'">First</a>
      <a class="button" ng-model="button.second" ng-click="click(button.second)" ng-class="button.second.clicked?'button-positive':'button-energized'">Second</a>
      <a class="button" ng-model="button.third" ng-click="click(button.third)" ng-class="button.third.clicked?'button-positive':'button-energized'">Third</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**edit:** In case you would like a leaner solution like the one Shay suggested, you can see the full implementation in Ionic on the [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjNQBQ), pasted below. The main difference is that the clicked function can not be written as he did, and it would produce an error. Anyways, take the solution which suits you best.

```js
angular.module('mySuperApp', ['ionic'])
.controller('MyCtrl',function($scope) {
  $scope.click = function(num) {
    $scope.var = num;
}

});
```

```html
<html ng-app="mySuperApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">   
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">    
    <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body class="padding" ng-controller="MyCtrl">    
    <div class="button-bar">
      <a class="button" ng-click="click(1)" ng-class="{'button-positive':var==1}">First</a>
      <a class="button" ng-click="click(2)" ng-class="{'button-positive':var==2}">Second</a>
      <a class="button" ng-click="click(3)" ng-class="{'button-positive':var==3}">Third</a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the codepen, I too edited the part that causes error... it's easier to spot these once you run them. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this might help you:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/18nyfzg2/)

**HTML**

```
  <a href="#" class="button" id="1">First</a>
  <a href="#" class="button" id="2">Second</a>
  <a href="#" class="button" id="3">Third</a>
```

**CSS**

```
a
{
    text-decoration:none;
}

.button
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    height:20px;
    width:60px;
    text-align:center;
    background:#0CA68F;
    color:white;
}

.active
{
    background:#188171;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("a").click(function()
{
  $(".button").removeClass("active");   
  $("#" + this.id).addClass("active");
});
```